# iPhone iOS how to programmatically generate gravatar like the one used by stack overflow from a unique user ID?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, gravatar

I'm working on **a medical app that may be a subject to HIPAA requirements**, and I'm thinking of **a good way to uniquely identify multiple users within the app** without using names or pictures. The concept of **a colored graphics avatar** comes to mind, like the one used by StackOverflow.

**Is there some sort of a library that I can use for this kind of dynamic graphic creation?** 
I'm interested in getting a UIImage representation of the gravatar.

Part of the requirement of the app may be sending messages to other users, and I think being able to dynamically generate a gravatar from the user id is much better option than worrying about sending/receiving/caching regular user avatars.

Thank you for your thoughts!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can find details about generating gravatar images [here](http://en.gravatar.com/site/implement/images/)

If you want to do it from iOS, you'll need a way to generate a hash of the user ID.  [Here is a category to add an MD5 hashing method to the NSString class](http://iphonedevelopertips.com/core-services/create-md5-hash-from-nsstring-nsdata-or-file.html).

If you add the NSString category at the link above to your project, you can then hash the user ID and build a url that will generate a unique gravatar image for your user like this:

```
int userID = 123456;

NSString *hashedUserID = [[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i", userID] MD5];
NSString *gravatarURLString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://www.gravatar.com/avatar/%@?d=identicon", hashedUserID];
NSURL *gravatarURL = [NSURL URLWithString:gravatarURLString];
```

Then you can create NSURLRequest with that URL to request the image and display it in your app.

Comment: Thank you for the info! I was under the impression that such images may be drawn dynamically, but apparently they are all coming form some web server. Oh well, maybe I can cache them for offline use!